# Binding to Variable and Converter in Code

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I am trying to make the `ListBoxItem` appear only when the bool `isInEditMode` is true. This is my variable:

```
private bool isInEditMode
{
    get { return Convert.ToBoolean(GetValue(IsInEditMode_Property)); }
    set { SetValue(IsInEditMode_Property, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty IsInEditMode_Property = DependencyProperty.Register("isInEditMode", typeof(bool), typeof(MainWindow), new PropertyMetadata(null));
```

This is where I add the `ListBoxItem`:

```
SurfaceListBoxItem slbi = new SurfaceListBoxItem();    

Binding visibilityBinding = new Binding("Visibility");
visibilityBinding.Source = isInEditMode;
visibilityBinding.Converter = new BoolToVisibility();
visibilityBinding.NotifyOnTargetUpdated = true;
slbi.SetBinding(SurfaceListBoxItem.VisibilityProperty, visibilityBinding);                    

myListBox.Items.Add(slbi);
```

However, the converter didn't get triggered when isInEditMode is changed. What went wrong? This is my converter btw, pretty straight forward:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
{
    if (System.Convert.ToBoolean(value) == true)
        return System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
    else
        return System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
}
```

I did a quick tested in XAML and this works though:

```
<Grid Visibility="{Binding Path=isInEditMode, ElementName=myMainWindow, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibility}, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}" />
```

Comment: There's out-of-box `BooleanToVisibilityConverter`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.booleantovisibilityconverter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the info! I have changed it but it's still not working... I suspect there's something wrong with `visibilityBinding.Source = isInEditMode;`, it's not binding...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your construction of `Binding` is wrong. `Source` is the object, that is data source for binding operation. `Path` (you're setting it via ctor parameter) is a path to data property in data source.

Hence, `Binding` should look like this:

```
var visibilityBinding = new Binding("isInEditMode");
visibilityBinding.Source = this;
visibilityBinding.Converter = new BoolToVisibility();
visibilityBinding.NotifyOnTargetUpdated = true;

// here you setting the target property - VisibilityProperty
slbi.SetBinding(SurfaceListBoxItem.VisibilityProperty, visibilityBinding);
```